# getElemntsByClassName is not working expectedly

Tags: javascript

Dom part-4

```js
var h1 = document.getElementsByClassName("h1");
 h1.getAttribute("class")//shows me error getAttribute is not function
```

```html
<h1 class="h1" id ="h1" alt>Dom part-4</h1>
```

I don't know why it is happened

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` method returns a collection of all elements. You can select the first return by using `[0]` Example `document.getElementsByClassName("h1")[0]`

Comment: h1 is a class name?  Looks like it could be a node name (`<h1>`), but I might be wrong.

Comment: `h1` shouldn't be a class name. You should try [`getElementsByTagName` as documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName).

Answer (score 1):

`h1` is not an element. From docs:

> Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names...

You have to use `h1[0]`. Here is the [docs for getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

```js
var h1 = document.getElementsByClassName("h1");
alert(h1[0].getAttribute("class"))
```

```html
<h1 class="h1">Test</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

**document.getElementsByClassName always return array of element object** on which you have made selection.

For example as you want to select "h1"
**document.getElementsByClassName will return array** of this element. No matter if its the only one in dom.

Put **document.getElementsByClassName("selector")[index]** to select exact element from DOM

```js
var h1 = document.getElementsByClassName("h1");
console.log(h1);

console.log(h1[0]);
```

```html
<h1 class="h1">my name abc</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like object, so you need to reference the element you want like it was an array element.

```
var h1 = document.getElementsByClassName("h1");
h1[0].getAttribute("class")
```

Example

```js
var h1 = document.getElementsByClassName("h1");
console.log( h1[0].getAttribute("class") )
```

```html
<div class="h1">test</div>
```